# print out multiple values of a taxonomy field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

In a taxonomy I have some fields for the terms. To print out 1 of these fields in a node.tpl I found this code:

```
<?php $term=taxonomy_term_load($node->field_hotel_tx_atmosphere['und'][0]['tid']);
$result=field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_tx_headline','text');
print render($result); ?>
```

But this way I get only the first value - there are multiple terms selected.

How can I get all selected terms printed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` in `$node->field_hotel_tx_atmosphere['und'][0]['tid']` means that you are taking only first term so you should loop through array to get all terms.

I recommend entity_metadata_wrapper (available with [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module):

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
foreach ($wrapper->field_hotel_tx_atmosphere->getIterator() as $delta => $term_wrapper) {
  // prepare and render field value:
  $result = field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $term_wrapper->value(), 'field_tx_headline', 'text');
  print render($result);
}
```

or build a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display selected data in the right way.

Comment: Thank you, zaporylie, it works. But it renders all terms in 1 line. I'd like to have every single term in a div or span.

Comment: I got it:

<?php $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
             foreach ($wrapper->field_hotel_tx_accomondation->getIterator() as $delta => $term_wrapper) {
              $result = field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $term_wrapper->value(), 'field_tx_headline', 'text');
                print '<li>' . render($result) . '</li>';
             } ?>